# Masterpage catalog via webDav

Tags: webdav

I've got WebDav set up on my Windows 2008 R2 environment (Desktop Experience and everything), but still can't seem to connect to the environment 100%. I can browse to the local instance on port 80, but that's about it.

Found and application called BitKinex, and it keeps returning "method not allowed" when browsing into the sub-directories?

I have Office 2010 SP1 installed on the machine as well, might it be something to do with Office?

Answer (score 1):

From what I noticed the Master Page and Page Layout Gallery is not being displayed when connecting to the root of your website. Instead, try connecting directly to the Master Page and Page Layout Gallery, by appending _catalogs/masterpage to the URL, eg. http://yoursite/_catalogs/masterpage.

Comment: I've done this, works fine. Would like to connect to WebDav, create a shared location and then access the content through Visual Studio that way, as VS does not support SharePoint out the box. Thought it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to start the WebClient service on your 2008 server.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer] for general guidelines.